# Cross-linking for ARM/QNX fails with indirect/transitive dependencies

Tags: unix, linker, arm, cross-compiling

I am trying to compile a simple project for QNX/ARM, which consists of a main executable and two shared libraries, liba and libb.

main depends on liba only and does not use anything from libb at all.
liba depends on libb.
So the dependency chain is: main -> liba -> libb. Therefore, libb is a indirect/transitive dependency of main.
liba.so is in the subdirectory liba/, libb.so is in the subdirectory libb/.

I link main the following way:

```
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -Wl,--no-undefined -lang-c++ -o linktest main.o -L$TARGET/lib -Llibb -Lliba -la
```

As you can see, because of the two -L lines, the linker should have no problem finding both libb and liba.

When I compile this with the QNX/ARM toolchain, I get an error:

```
ntoarm-ld: warning: libb.so, needed by liba/liba.so, not found (try using -rpath or -rpath-link)
```

Using strace confirms that ld never even looks into the libb/ directory, despite this being specified with -L.

Why does it not look into the -L directories here?

Comment: On IRC, I was told this behavior depends on the used linker. Some pull in indirect dependencies automatically, some don't. That surprises me greatly though, and I'd still like to know why ld completely ignores the -L path

Answer (score 0):

`-lb` is missing! `L` specifies the path, while `l` the actual library. Add `-lb` at the end of your build command:

```
qcc -Vgcc_ntoarmv7le -Wl,--no-undefined -lang-c++ -o linktest main.o \
-L$TARGET/lib -Llibb -Lliba -la -lb
```

If you want to eliminate this build-time dependency, consider using *libb* via runtime [dynamic loading](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_loading) from *liba* using [dlopen()](http://linux.die.net/man/3/dlopen).

UPDATE:

As *tmcguire* pointed out, behavior of indirect linking for shared libraries varies from linker to linker. According to [this article](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/NattyNarwhal/ToolchainTransition), responsible `ld` option is `--no-copy-dt-needed-entries` (sometimes called `--no-add-needed`, which in latest `gcc` releases (>4.5?) is enabled by default.

Another interesting option is `--as-needed`:

> The `--as-needed` flag is passed to the GNU linker (GNU ld). The flag
>   tells the linker to link in the produced binary only the libraries
>   containing symbols actually used by the binary itself. This binary can
>   be either a final executable or another library.

Additional reading is [here](http://wiki.debian.org/ToolChain/DSOLinking), and [here](http://www.gentoo.org/proj/en/qa/asneeded.xml).

Comment: Yes, I didn't specify -lb, since that is an indirect dependency. I thought the linker would figure out that liba depends on libb and therefore pull in libb automatically. I mean, ld warns me that it can't find libb.so, so it should know it needs to link against it, and even ignores the -L that tells it where to find libb.so...